# Reload .emacs in emacs server without closing current emacs clients

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Background:
Using Emacs 24.2.1.

I start Emacs client and server with this alias:

```
emacsclient -nw -a="" -c "$@"
```

I want to reload my `.emacs` file after I update it without having Emacs server terminate current clients. Basically, right now, I would edit the `.emacs` file using `emacsclient`. Then, I do `M-x load-file`. It then asks

```
The current server still has clients; delete them? (yes or no)
```

Saying yes would reload the `.emacs` file but will also terminate all current clients, which forces my client to close since it just got terminated.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Actually, after some more tinkering I found out what was wrong. I had (server-start) as the first line in my .emacs file, which is unnecessary given the way I am invoking emacsclient. As a result the first action it takes is restart the server. Dumb bug.

Answer (score 1):

The only place I could find this message in the Emacs source code is in the function `server-start`:

```lisp
(defun server-start (&optional leave-dead inhibit-prompt)
 ...
  (when (or (not server-clients)
            ;; Ask the user before deleting existing clients---except
            ;; when we can't get user input, which may happen when
            ;; doing emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)" in daemon mode.
            (cond
             ((and (daemonp)
                   (null (cdr (frame-list)))
                   (eq (selected-frame) terminal-frame))
              leave-dead)
             (inhibit-prompt t)
             (t (yes-or-no-p
                 "The current server still has clients; delete them? ")))) ...
```

I would assume that you are executing `server-start` somewhere in your .emacs and that this is causing the issue. If that is the case you would remove the expression and reloading .emacs should work as you had expected.

PS: I would have posted a comment but I'm not allowed to do that yet, so I'm writing an answer :)